# Receive Spring's Entity with @JoinColumn in RESTful web service

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa

I have these tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ref.doc (
    id       serial PRIMARY KEY,
    iddoc    integer NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    docname  varchar(254) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE person (
    id       serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name     varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL, 
    doctype  integer DEFAULT NULL REFERENCES ref.doc(iddoc)
);
```

I need to build a RESTful web service using Spring which receives JSONs and saves them into the database after some verification. For example, there's a record with `iddoc = 2` in `ref.doc`. So the JSON for `person` looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "doctype": 2
}
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Person add(@RequestBody Person person) {
        // some logic
        personRepository.saveAndFlush(person);
        return person;
    }
}
```

I have these entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "ref")
public class Doc {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private long id;

    private Integer iddoc;
    private String docname;

    ...
}

@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "doctype", referencedColumnName = "iddoc", nullable = false)
    private Doc doc;

    ...
}
```

And in this case `doc` in `person` is always `null`, and it's pretty much understandable. But how to implement the behavior I need?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this link?

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077819/java-se/understanding-jpa-part-2-relationships-the-jpa-way.html

In particular look at the relationship between order table and customer table.

For what i understood you need a Person to have multiple Documents.
So try to change the definition

```
private Doc doc;
```

to

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="person", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   private List<Doc> docs;
```

and in Doc class try add this:

```
 @ManyToOne(optional=false)
 @JoinColumn(name="doctype",referencedColumnName="iddoc")
   private Person person;
```

This should be the correct way to implement the behaviour you need, not 100% sure.
Here is another link that explaines how to achieve the solution you need:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany

Answer (score 0):

```
        @RestController
        public class PersonController {

            @Autowired
            PersonRepository personRepository;

            @Autowired
            DocRepository docRepository;

            @Transactional
            @RequestMapping("/add")
            @ResponseBody
            public void add(@RequestBody Person person) {
                Doc doc=docRepository.findByIddoc(person.getDoc().getIddoc());
                if(!(doc==null)){
                Person personAdd=new Person();
                personAdd.setName("name");
                personAdd.setDoc(doc);
                personRepository.saveAndFlush(person);
                }
            }
        }



    @Entity
    public class Person {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @JsonIgnore
        private long id;

        private String name;

        @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "doctype", referencedColumnName = "iddoc", nullable = false)
        private Doc doc;






@Entity
@Table(schema = "demo")
public class Doc {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonIgnore
    private long id;

    private Integer iddoc;
    private String docname;
```